# Queue synchronization

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am working with Java rabbitmq API. This how my app looks like:
[image]

Publisher `A` sends jobs to `Q1`, then many consumers `B` do the job and create new job and send it to `Q2`, where many consumer `C` do the job.

I want to make sure that no duplicated jobs are sent to `Q2`, how can I achieve this?

Take in mind two scenarios:

1. `B` crash after sending job to `Q2` but before sending acknowledgment to `Q1` that he completed the job
2. `B` crash after sending acknowledgment to `Q1` but before sending job to `Q2`

Comment: Using `reddis` or `memcached` to check if the job has been submitted already?

Comment: @AvihooMamka I don't understand. Can you provide a full answer please

Comment: Can you do some sort of system that manages double entries or would that consume too much time? I'm picturing something like that: Q1 gives every entry an increasing number, Q2 stores a list with those number in order (every time something enters Q2, it's number is bubbled into that list). Assuming that usually the order in which the B process the jobs does not scramble the numbers too much, the question whether something is in the list or not should be fast to answer since only a small amount of the list needs to be traversed.

Comment: @Aziuth You cannot assume that Jobs from Q1 will be finished in the same time as jobs from Q2, especially that there are many jobs in each queue running simultaneously.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman And what is the problem with that in regard to my proposal?

Comment: @Aziuth sorry, I misunderstood you. This solve half of it. B will still have to do it's job over again, but only this time Q2 will ignore it. Also if I had a longer chain, Q2 would have to give new ids for jobs to Q3. Q10 would have to manage 9 ids. It's pretty complicated.

Comment: Its a really good question at first, one solution that comes to my mind is bit complicated but might work. We create another queue which maintains the backup. So I mean when the consumer receives the message it immediately pushes the message on the temp queue and starts processing it. After the processing is done and second job is submitted successfully we can delete message in the  temp queue. So every time we need to see if the message is there in the temp queue. 
So that way even if the consumer crashes and we Ack we still have the backup for the same message and you wont lose that message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make sure that no duplicated jobs are sent to Q2, how can I achieve this?

you can't. not even on Q1.

the nature of distributed systems and the CAP theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) says this is impossible, even if the goal is accomplished the vast majority of the time.

in light of that, what you need do is plan for how you will handle the times when a duplicate message is accidentally created.

the most common method is some sort of idempotence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) - a way to guarantee that the same message will only be processed once. or, maybe more accurately, a way to say that the same message can be processed an unlimited number of times, but will only cause change / have an effect on the system once.

---

in general, though, your situation with multiple queues and consumers that need to process things in order is calling for a "Saga" or "Process Manager" - a long running, asynchronous workflow.

You can read up on this idea of a "Process Manager" in the Enterprise Integration Patterns book, and there are a lot of good libraries around that will implement the details for you.

- http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ProcessManager.html
- http://kellabyte.com/2012/05/30/clarifying-the-saga-pattern/

Comment: I can't find Process Manager ques for java, what should I search?

Comment: i'm out of my depth with Java, unfortunately... i have an article covering the concept in JavaScript, though. it may be useful as a guide, even though the tech / implementation would be different: https://derickbailey.com/2015/08/10/managing-workflow-in-long-running-javascript-processes/